# Count if cell not blank

Tags: vba, excel

Hi All I have 2 formulas i'm trying to run but struggling to get the COUNTIF to calculate only if the cell isn't blank.

```
Sheets("Home").Select
If Range("A2:A14").Count = "13" Then

MsgBox "Current Load Full Please Complete & Export", vbCritical

Exit Sub

End If
```

2nd Code

```
Sheets("Home").Select
If Range("A2:A14").Count < "13" Then

MsgBox "Shipment is short do you want to continue?", vbCritical vbYesNo

Exit Sub

End If
```

On the 2nd code if vbYes then run code if vbNo then exit sub.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Have you conducted any research?

Comment: Sorry. Using the code above it is counting all the blank cells as as well as the populated cells. I need to be able to only count the cells that have content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do some action depending on the condition "all cells in range A2:A14 are filled or not" - then this code might be the answer.

```
Sub check_count()

Sheets("Home").Select

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Worksheets("Home").Range("A2:A14")

'using excel's built in function CountA to check count of non-blank cells
'if the count is 13 - then msgbox
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange) = 13 Then
    MsgBox "Current Load Full Please Complete & Export", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
'if the count is less then 13 - then do following
Else:
    msg1 = MsgBox("Shipment is short do you want to continue?", vbYesNo)
    If msg1 = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "Enter missing products in A2:A14" 'you can run some code here as well
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to count all non-blank cells in a given range, you could use:

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A14").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count < 13 Then
```